American English: (1) I never ate this before. (2) I have never eaten this before
Context: My friend give me a new food. I eat. This is the first time I have eaten this food. The food is new to me.
My friend: Try this. I am sure you will like it.
Me: (After some bites)
Wow! This is so delicous. I never ate / have never eaten this before.
So in American English, can I use either sentences in this context ? Any difference?

(1) I never ate this before. (simple past)
(2) I have never eaten this before.(present perfect)


I have also heard American English speakers say this, many times. It is common, accepted, informal language. That doesn't make it correct. In standard English, it is preferrable to use the present perfect tense for experiences or actions that have relevance to the present moment. The more widely accepted version would be: "I have never eaten this before".
All dialects of English - British, American, Australian and many more - contain informal speech, colloquialisms, idioms, slang etc that are particular to that dialect and sometimes go against the rules of grammar. American English is so widely heard due to the far-reach of US movies and television that more than just native US speakers recognise the idioms. That's how I recognised it, despite being a British English speaker. But if I heard a non-native speaker use it, my first thought would be that they have learned to speak English from watching Hollywood movies. It stands out as being American. So, it's your choice - if you want to sound like a local, then imitate how they speak; if you want to be more universally understood then learn textbook English.

Perhaps lots of Americans would say, “I never ate this before,” meaning before the moment of utterance, and maybe l am either unobservant or forgetful. But to this native speaker of American English it doesn’t sound even casual. It sounds somewhat quirky and marks the speaker as non-native.

I have never eaten this before. is standard, sure.  But for "I never ate", I just don't buy the reading of it as always AmE.

@Lambie as in another post, you say "The "did" means the speaker sees it as over and finished. You do not need to mention a specific or implied past time. The simple past tense implies it even if not stated." So, does this also apply to this case? Does the sentence with simple past "never ate" sound unnatural to you in this context?


I have never eaten this before.

is the correct usage.

I never ate this before

is quite common in the U.S., at least in the South, particularly among less-educated white people. It all depends on where you live and whom you talk to. It's speech that commonly also includes the word "ain't." For example:

I ain't never ate this before.

You should never try to imitate this because you probably won't get it right. Even native speakers who aren't exposed to it don't sound natural when they try to imitate it.
